# Why is my constructor not initializing a variable correctly?

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

So I am trying to read in a file and create an arralist of those objects. The number of objects within the file is what I want my numItems variable to be set to, but I am getting an error.

```
public class Warehouse
{
// instance variables (fields)  
private final static int MAX = 60;
private ArrayList <Item> stock;
private int numItems;

// the constructor
public Warehouse()
{
    stock = new ArrayList<Item>();
    numItems = loadData();
}


public int loadData(File infile) throws IOException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (infile);
    int number = 0;

    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        String item = in.nextLine();
        String [] items = item.split(" ");
        String itemNum = items[0];
        String itemName = items[1];
        int onHand = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);
        int committed = Integer.parseInt(items[3]);
        int onOrder = Integer.parseInt(items[4]);
        double price = Double.parseDouble(items[5]);
        int reOrderPt = Integer.parseInt(items[6]);
        int econOrder = Integer.parseInt(items[7]);
        stock.add(number, new Item(itemNum, itemName, onHand, committed, onOrder, price, reOrderPt, econOrder));
        number++;
    }

    return number;
}
```

Here is my main where I am reading the file and passing it into the loadData method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    // complete the main by adding the necessary variables and statements
    int choice;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Warehouse inStock = new Warehouse();
    String number = "";
    int amount = 0;

    File infile = new File("inventory.txt");
    inStock.loadData(infile);
```

Comment: 'I am getting an error' is not a problem description, and a compiler error is not an example of 'my constructor not initializing a variable correctly'.

Comment: `int loadData(File infile)` -- you cannot then call it as `numItems = loadData();`, you must call it with a `File` argument.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're getting an error because `loadData()` expects a `File` argument and you're not passing any.
2. Why would you need to keep track of the number of items when you can just call [`ArrayList.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--)?

Comment: I'm passing the file from my main

Comment: `numItems = loadData();` Where's the file?

Comment: I updated the question to show where I am loading it from

Comment: You still have an incorrect call inside your `Warehouse` constructor.

Comment: so would I just initialize numItems by stock.size()?

Comment: You don't need `numItems` at all. Just get `stock.size()` whenever you need that information.